# how to generate Ivy enabled umd bundles

Tags: angular-ivy

We have an Angular CLI application and we use CDN scripts bundles. We we copy these bundles from the bundles folder within the npm package (e.g. node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js). We would like to use Ivy. How can we Ivy-enable those bundles in a custom fashion? Can we run a command or script on these scripts.

Is it possible to run ngcc on a single js file to generate a new js file?

Answer (score 0):

By inserting following script in the package.json and doing an npm install the bundles will be adapted to be Ivy compliant:

postinstall": "ngcc"